# Avoid showing the number of chapter.section in the list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents

Is it possible to not showing the numbers in front of the figures in the list of figures when using `\listoffigures`?

E.g. just showing figure a, figure b, figure c, instead of 1.1 figure a, 2.1 figure b, ...

Example of code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\author{TeXstudio Team}
\title{Simple Book Example}
\date{January 2013}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\mainmatter
\chapter{AAA}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}[hpb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{figure a}
\end{figure}

\chapter{BBB}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}[hpb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}
    \caption{figure b}
\end{figure}

\chapter{CCC}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}[hpb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-c}
    \caption{figure c}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using package `tocbasic` (version 3.20 or newer):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{tocbasic}[2016/05/10]% needs version 3.20 or newer
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\gobble,
  numwidth=0pt,
  indent=0pt
]{tocline}{figure}
\newcommand\gobble[1]{}

\begin{document}

\author{TeXstudio Team}
\title{Simple Book Example}
\date{January 2013}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\mainmatter
\chapter{AAA}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}[hpb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{figure a}
\end{figure}

\chapter{BBB}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}[hpb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}
    \caption{figure b}
\end{figure}

\chapter{CCC}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}[hpb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-c}
    \caption{figure c}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]